# How to handle button inside input on focus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

the problem is that when ever in focusing the password input the button show up but when i try to click the button its lose the focus on the input and then the button disappear.

```js
<div className="input-wrapper">
  <input
    onFocus={() => setShowButton(true)}
    onBlur={() => setShowButton(false)}
    title="password"
    type={type === 'password' && toggle ? 'text' : 'password'}
    {...props}
  />
  {showButton && (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={type === 'password' ? 'password' : ''}
      onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
    >
      {toggle ? <ShowPasswordIcon /> : <HidePasswordIcon />}
    </button>
  )}
</div>
```

well i want that the button will be somehow included in the input focus (if that make sense somehow)

Comment: use the `onMouseDown` event instead of the `onClick` event for the button. This way, the focus will stay on the input even when clicking on the button.

Comment: well it half working, since it does change the value between false and true but the button disappears after every click for obvious reasons

Comment: add a condition to show the button only when the input has focus and the `toggle` state is true.

Comment: but toggle only change the content of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css pseudo-class [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) on the wrapper. When the wrapper on any of it's children (button / input) is focused, the button would be visible:

```css
.input-wrapper:not(:focus-within) > button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper"> <!-- className in JSX -->
  <input>
  
  <button>Toogle</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within):

```css
.input-wrapper button {
  display: none;
}
.input-wrapper:focus-within button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

React example, with focus management (keeps focus on input, keeps cursor position and/or selection, if present):

```js
const { useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect, useCallback } = React

const App = () => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)
  const [toggle, input, wrapper] = [
    useCallback(() => setShowPassword((b) => !b), []),
    useRef(null),
    useRef(null)
  ]
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    input &&
      wrapper &&
      wrapper.current.contains(document.activeElement) &&
      input.current.focus()
  }, [showPassword])

  return (
    <div className="input-wrapper" ref={wrapper}>
      <input
        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
        defaultValue="password"
        ref={input}
      />
      <button onClick={toggle}>{showPassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```css
.input-wrapper button {
  display: none;
}
.input-wrapper:focus-within button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Notes:

- `:focus-within` global support is [slightly less than 96%](https://caniuse.com/css-focus-within) at the time of this writing. To make it work for everyone, you'll need to include [focus-within-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/focus-within-polyfill) in your project
- avoids using `:not()` selector, (e.g: `.input-wrapper:not(:focus-within) button`) as `:not()` has an additional lack of browser support of [~4% globally](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_not).